# New dark theme colours have been overly de-saturated relative to other sites?

Tags: discussion, dark-mode, theme

Has the new dark theme overly de-saturated its colours? This seems to have led to a perceived reduction in contrast too. The theme now looks flat and dull compared to its former version.

The light theme(s) are looking good; they seem to have received a boost in contrast where it matters.

**Current dark theme**

Note the orange bar at the top is barely orange. The same can be said for the red circle on the review cues icon, badge colours and the light blue links/buttons.

[image]

**Example of another site**

Notice the colours are actually colours (blue links/buttons, green answer status et cetera).

[image]

Comment: There's another question active complaining that the the dark theme now has *too much* contrast....

Comment: Agreed, the blues, especially the buttons, are way too washed out in dark mode.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Talking about different things, I think. To me it seems the *foreground* elements got brighter / washed out, *decreasing* contrast between different foreground elements, but *increasing* contrast between foreground and *background*.

Comment: Problems can be noted here (and probably already are by the looks of it): https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393939/new-colors-launched .

Comment: The desaturation in dark mode seems like a real problem to me, too. I used to see notifications pop up out of the corner of my eye, but now they are easily missed unless I am looking right at them....

Comment: I didn't see this "question" and created my own to note the same thing. I find the green and red to be too washed out. The orange is also a bit light--but just OK. Overall, I preferred the more saturated look of the previous theme. I switched to the high-contrast theme, but even there, the colors are now even more washed out due to the very black background. As the OP said, the light theme looks quite nice--for a light theme--but I really can't stand these blinding white themes. I sure hope these colors can be reverted back to what they were. The colors were just perfect previously.